# Can't get contents of directory in home and can't copy file there

Tags: debian, file-copy, home

I'm trying to copy a command (`istioctl`) in my home directory on Debian so that I can always use it, as it will be added to my PATH variable automatically.

I tried ("link1" is a symbolic link to a hard drive containing the istioctl):

```
TestUser@ComputerName:~$ cp ~/link1/istio-1.12.2/bin/istioctl ~/cmd
```

and

```
TestUser@ComputerName:~$ cp ~/link1/istio-1.12.2/bin/istioctl ~/bin
```

neither directory existed in `~` before that. At least `ll` and `ls` didn't show them.

but this is what I get:

```
TestUser@ComputerName:~$ ll ~
total 171856
-rwxr-xr-x 1 TestUser users 87990272 Jan 24 19:47 bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 TestUser users 87990272 Jan 24 19:50 cmd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 TestUser users       38 Jan 13 18:16 link1 -> /some/path1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 TestUser users       39 Jan 13 18:10 link2 -> /some/path2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 TestUser users       38 Jan 13 18:17 link3 -> /some/path3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 TestUser users       38 Jan 13 18:15 link4 -> /some/path4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 TestUser users       38 Jan 13 18:15 link5 -> /some/path5
TestUser@ComputerName:~$
TestUser@ComputerName:~$ ll ~/bin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 TestUser users 87990272 Jan 24 19:47 /home/TestUser/bin
TestUser@ComputerName:~$
TestUser@ComputerName:~$ ll ~/cmd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 TestUser users 87990272 Jan 24 19:50 /home/TestUser/cmd
```

I don't understand why the `cmd` and `bin` folders behave this way and why they don't contain the file.

Also tried as `root`:

```
root@ComputerName:~# cp ~/link1/istio-1.12.2/bin/istioctl /home/TestUser/bin
```

same thing.

Comment: you created two copies: one is called `bin`, the other is called `cmd`, it behaved as asked (and I guess not as intended).

Comment: You are coyping a file, not a folder - so the result is a file, not a folder (there is no `d` indicating a directory in the `ls` output). `cmd` and `bin` are two copies of `istioctl`.

Comment: It sounds like you expected there to already be `~/bin` and `~/cmd` directories to be on that system, but they were not, leading to the results you saw. Were those directories deleted at some point?

Comment: `bin` and `cmd` are *not* folders, but plain files (as you can easily see in the `ls` output).

Comment: to all the comments - D'OH! I completely messed up how `cp` works! xD I thought telling it to copy to `~/bin` would create the directory `bin` and copy the file with the original name there. Thank you all, that was my mistake, I'll fix it, now. :) Anyone feel free to make an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistakenly thought that the `cp` command would create a directory at the destination and then put the source file in that directory. It doesn't work like that -- to put a source file into a destination directory, that directory has to already exist; otherwise, `cp` will simply create a destination *file* of that name.

This behavior is described (among `man cp` and other places) in [the POSIX standard for cp](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html):

> `cp [-Pfip] source_file target_file`

> `cp [-Pfip] source_file... target`

> The first synopsis form is denoted by two operands, neither of which are existing files of type directory. The cp utility shall copy the contents of source_file ... to the destination path named by target_file.

> The second synopsis form is denoted by two or more operands where the -R option is not specified and the first synopsis form is not applicable. It shall be an error if any source_file is a file of type directory, if target does not exist, or if target does not name a directory. The cp utility shall copy the contents of each source_file ... to the destination path named by the concatenation of target, a single  character if target did not end in a , and the last component of source_file.

Essentially, you need to `cp source-file destination-file` or `cp source-file pre-existing-directory`.

To achieve want you want, `mkdir ~/bin` or `mkdir ~/cmd` and *then* `cp ~/link1/istio-1.12.2/bin/istioctl ~/bin`.  It sounds like you may have added your $HOME directory to your PATH. That's legal, but slightly less common. More common would be to add a `~/bin` or `~/cmd` directory to your PATH. Ensure you've added *that* directory to your PATH for success.